# ReCreate Excel file from BASE 64 encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

I have a client (React Client - with DropZone) that sends an Excel file to the server

```
 const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {

    // ... Some code 

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onabort = () => console.log("file reading was aborted");
    reader.onerror = () => console.log("file reading has failed");
    reader.onload = async () => {
      // Send file the Server
      const result = reader.result;
      const body = {
        url: result
      };

      await axiosInstance.post("/api/upload", body);
    };

    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => reader.readAsDataURL(file));
  }, []);
```

And the Node JS server receives it as :

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {

  // ... Some code 
  console.log(req.body.url);

}
```

**req.body.url:**

`data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADA ...`

How can I create the Excel file same as the client has it ?